# Directly viewing WebM or OGG file works in Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: html, video, ogg, webm

I'm having an issue with getting local videos working for the HTML5 Video element.

If I try and view a local OGG or WebM file directly, in Firefox 16.0.2 it works, but in chrome 22 it does not work!

However, if I view an OGG file on another webserver, it works correctly.

For example this file

http://www.quackit.com/video/pass-countdown.ogg

Works correctly for me, but if I save it onto my own server as

http://test.jammaloo.com/pass.ogg

Then it works in Firefox, but Chrome will not play it.

I believe the mimetype is being set correctly, can anyone help me track down the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First of all try with adding support for more video types

Link - http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/client/how-to-embed-video-using-html5.html

> video id="sampleMovie" width="640" height="360" preload controls

```
<source src="HTML5Sample_H264.mov" type='video/mp4;' />
<source src="HTML5Sample_Ogg.ogv" type='video/ogg;' />
<source src="HTML5Sample_WebM.webm" type='video/webm;' />
```

> video

- Second check your .htaccess file for content type - add mime type for webm, ogg, mp4

Link - http://docs.sublimevideo.net/troubleshooting

Link - http://www.htaccess-guide.com/adding-mime-types/

These solved my problem of playing video in HTML5 video tag. Hope it helps you too.

As i checked in the CHROME your content is not getting loaded with correct "TYPE"

If applicable (and nothing works) you can use- http://www.longtailvideo.com/players

Comment: Thanks Joddy, I tried your suggestions and still had issues, which made me realise it must be something on my end. I ended up removing Varnish from my stack, and now it is working correctly!