# Can I get codecs for mpeg-4 , 3gpp and pcm extensions for Chrome Browser ?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, html5-video, html5-audio, video-codecs

Now , I currently used  HTML video and audio control. What is codecs for mpeg-4 and 3gpp extension in Chrome Browser ? I tested Firefox , it's work both. But I try in Chrome Browser , it's not work although same codecs. Has some others codecs or content type?

Here is my function:

```
function DisplayAudio(source, fileName) {

        var audioElm = document.getElementById("audioControl");
        var audioSource = document.getElementById("source");
        audioElm.setAttribute('src', source);

        var n = fileName.indexOf(".");
        var extension = fileName.substring(fileName.length, n + 1);

        if (extension == "3gp") {
            audioSource.type = 'audio/3gpp';                
        }
        else if (extension == "3gpp") {
             // testing
            //audioSource.type = 'audio/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"';                
        }
        else if (extension == "mpeg4") {
             // testing
            //audioSource.type = 'audio/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"';                
        }
        else if (extension == "pcm") {

        }
}
```

Comment: Anyone help ??? I need help for that !! Please give me advice how can I get correct codec and content type for mpeg-4 and 3gpp files.

Comment: What have you tried? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245078/directly-viewing-webm-or-ogg-file-works-in-firefox-but-not-in-chrome)

Comment: I already tried for that , still not ok.For mpeg-4, codecs will be H.264 but It's only work for FireFox, not for Chrome .